# Visual Studio 2017 v15.9 Storyboard designer cannot connect to Mac while VS is connected to Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xamarin, storyboard

Visual Studio 2017 v15.9 on Windows 10 has apparently a new bug: the storyboard designer cannot connect to Mac. Previously in 15.8, the storyboard could connect and many features are working fine, however the ImageView could not work properly. After upgrading to to VS 2017 v15.9, the storyboard editor could not connect to Mac thus could not be opened, while VS is actually connecting to Mac and is able to compile and debug and deploy iOS app to simulators and devices.

I am having Mac Mini and xcode 10.1, but no VS for Mac. It is easy to replicate: just create a new Xamarin app with iOS project. After compiling and testing in simulators running in mac to prove things are OK, then double click on either LaunchScreen.storyboard or Main.storyboard created by scaffolding, then the designer tries to connect to Mac and end up with error message: "The iOS Designer requires an active connection to a Mac server. Please connect to a Mac to enable the designer.".

Now all my iOS apps work however I could not alter any storyboard. I don't like modifying the XML directly in a text editor.

I had spent hours researching solutions or hacks, so far no luck. Do you have some ideas? Cheers.

Comment: My current workaround is to create a dummy project in xCode and use the storyboard editor there, and then manually copy the xml back to the Windows machine.Having to learn the strange UI of xcode, and whole process may be just slightly better than drafting xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [problem report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/383487/xamarin-ios-designer-not-working-with-159-and-xama.html) that matches your bug description.

Visual Studio 15.9.2 has just been [released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.9.2), so try updating Visual Studio.

Here is a snippet of the Visual Studio 15.9.2 release notes:

**Issues Fixed in 15.9.2**

- Xamarin iOS designer not working with 15.9 and Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.10.

Comment: thanks for the update. I haven't updated to 15.9.2 yet still with 15.9. However this morning when connecting to Mac from Windows, VS 2017 updated the mono lib in xcode to the latest. Previously I had done such update to latest mono manually in Mac, however, VS reported implementable issue so I had to reverse back. Very strange. I will be checking soon and report back here.

Comment: confirmed that 15.9.2 fixes the problem. Hopefully such bug won't come back as it had reappeared a few times in last few years for different causes.